# How can i properly read an input from stdin with a buffer without truncating any words?

Tags: c, linux, buffer, posix, stdin

Hi i'm coding a simple program that intends to read some text from the stdin, then find some words in that text and replace it by "?" characters and finally drop the result in the stdout.

My problem is that if the current buffer ends in the middle of a word and i'm searching that word, the "strstr" function wouldnt find it as a hit.

**Example:**

With Buffer of 10 and finding the word "amazing"

Input: "Wordnet is a truly amazing piece of software and we use it a lot at Roistr for semantic relevance. One useful part of it is that each synset has examples of the word sense in use. But sometimes, these can mislead a little"

First Buffer: "Wordnet is" -> no hit

Second Buffer: " a truly a" -> no hit

Third Buffer: "mazing pie" -> no hit

As you can see in that third buffer i got a false negative for the word amazing because it was chopped off by the buffer length.

I need a solution that doesnt depend on the buffer size, beacause for example a buffer[500] would solve the problem in this example but if i got a 50000 input the problem probably will appear again.

Thanks

Sorry for my english.

**My Code:**

```
    char* aux = "is";
    char* pch;
    char buff[100];
    int readd;


    int stringsize = strlen(aux);


    while (((readd = read(0, buff, sizeof buff)) > 0)) {

        pch = strstr(buff, aux);

        if (pch != 0) {
            strncpy(pch, "?????????????????", stringsize);
        }

        write(1, buff, readd);
    }
```

**Other Details:**

Lenguage: C

Environment: Linux/POSIX

Comment: Make the buffer dynamic, read a character at a time until you get a newline, appending to the buffer, reallocate the buffer when full. Or use [`getline`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html) which will make sure you get a whole line, and allocates the memory for you.

Comment: @holyknight. If the file contains lines you may use fgets() that loads a single line at time (if the buffer you use may contain the bigger line in the file). However you have to take care of hyphenation. Another approach may be to take all words that are followed by a space (or \t \n \r). So at the end of the buffer remains only a word or a piece of word. Then you copy those remaining byte at the top of the buffer and load a new line from the file (taking care the buffer contains some data).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to get around this issue.

One of them (and closest probably to your solution) is to read the input character by character and detect the start and the end of each word (using whitespaces as delimiters). When you get to the end of a word, you compare it with the one you're searching for and you're done.

The above can be simplified using formatted input (something like scanf), which allows you to read up to the first whitespace.

A more complicated way would be to read as you do it now and if the last word in the current buffer is not finished (you can check this by verifying if your buffer ends with a whitespace for example), put the last part of the buffer (the part starting from the last space to the end) back to stdin (using something like ungetch()). And when you read again the buffer, you will get the full word.